# Postman Request to GET query with Multiple List<String> Parameters

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to test a Multi Module Spring WebMVC API endpoint using Postman. This is Spring-MVC web app & using other frameworks too.
I want to know how to make a request to this URL.

My Controller File looks like this.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/xyz")
public class XyzWebController {

  @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
  @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseBody
  public List<XyzChild> getProperties(@RequestParam XyzQueryDTO query) {
    return childService.getAll(query);
  }

...

}
```

XyzQueryDTO.java looks like this.

```
public class XyzQueryDTO {

  List<String> properties;

  List<String> applications;


  public XyzQueryDTO() {
  }

  public XyzQueryDTO(List<String> properties, 
      List<String> applications) {
    super();
    this.properties = properties;
    this.applications = applications;
  }

...

}
```

Please assist me with the URL with which i can test this API.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more simple and correct to use `RequestMethod.POST` instead of `RequestMethod.GET` and `@RequestBody` instead of `@RequestParam`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
  public List<XyzChild> getProperties(@RequestBody XyzQueryDTO query) {
    return childService.getAll(query);
  }
```

And you can use `@RestController` instead of `@Controller` and remove `@ResponseBody`

For data type conversion use jackson librairy.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
 <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
 <version>2.8.8</version>
</dependency>
```

In Postman you can fill your `XyzQueryDTO` in the `BODY` as `json`

Comment: Yes, I am going to make changes, Thank You for your Answer.